# PayPal REST Sandbox API giving INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I finished my PayPal REST API integration yesterday for executing simple payments through my website. My script does the following things:

- gets a bearer token
- creates a payment (allowing paypal as the only payment method)
- sends to user to PayPal for authorisation
- executes the payment

This was all working perfectly in the Sandbox yesterday.

Today I tried it (still in the Sandbox) and the execute command is returning an "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR" message. The debug_id from my most recent attempt was 93a4116223d6e.

What is particularly strange is that the payment has been processed correctly. When I log in to the sandbox accounts for the buyer and seller the transaction shows up there as usual.

Any idea why I am suddenly getting these error messages?

Comment: I have just run a test transaction on the live server and it behaves exactly as expect - no internal service errors. So why has the sandbox server suddenly started throwing errors?

Comment: I am also getting the same issue on sandbox  with response status as 500.  I think something is happening with their sandbox environment. Creditcard payment works fine.

Comment: Hi, I think I have a problem that is similar to yours, still trying to figure out how to fix it : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903783/php-paypal-auth-capture-nvp-integration-troubles). Can you confirm this can be a similar issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I have also a problem with the Sandbox environment.

Payments with an US account returns an INTERNAL SERVICE ERROR, but with other EU accounts the payments are completed.

Using PayPal as payment method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have stopped doing it now. I am putting this one down to an error at PayPal's end. It only seemed to last for a day or two.