# PayPal REST API [Sandbox] - INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR on payment sale execute

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

i've been using PayPal REST API since some months to handle sale payments programmatically without problems, both on live and sanbox platform. From a couple of days I figured that, only for sanbox, is impossible to finalize (execute) payments using resource POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/execute, indeed I get every time INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR response with status code 500.

Last response:

`Got Http response code 500 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/execute. {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"2205fb9528a0f"}`

Any idea about what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

full disclosure, I work at PayPal leading developer advocacy.

There was an issue with sandbox today and we escalated it through to try to have it resolved. I'm being told that the issue should now be resolved. In my tests on sandbox, the payments are going through. Can you please let me know if you're still encountering the 500 errors? If so, I'll send that back to the team.

Comment: Problem still present, just tried different times and got every time status code 500 with the same error of the main question. Here's some debug_id received with last responses: 649fb46ba909b, 33b4883790d67, 9587791a2a2ad

Comment: Thanks @lorenzoasr, those debug ids will help. After monitoring traffic following the patch the team put in place, they did notice higher latency, which is most likely the cause of some failures. Some cases have been resolved, but they're still working on all failure instances. I'll report back once I know more.

Answer (score 0):

Others are experiencing similar issues:
[PayPal REST Sandbox API giving INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38804016/paypal-rest-sandbox-api-giving-internal-service-error)

I'm experiencing the same only when using 'paypal' as the payment type. Submit a ticket to paypal at:
https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/home