# INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR while executing payment from paypal in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, paypal

Getting below error while executing payment of paypal:

> {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error
> has
> occurred","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"a997a9f72d8f6"}

Here is the code for payment execution:

```
var apiContext = PaypalConfiguration.GetAPIContext();
            var paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution() { payer_id = payerId };
            var payment = new Payment() { id = paymentId };
            // Execute authorization.
            var executedPayment = payment.Execute(apiContext, paymentExecution);// Execute the payment
            if (executedPayment.state.ToLower() == "approved")
            {
                var auth = payment.transactions[0].related_resources[0].authorization;

                var capture = new Capture()
                {
                    amount = amount,
                    is_final_capture = true
                };

                var responseCapture = auth.Capture(apiContext, capture);
                return responseCapture;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

While there are many possible reasons for an INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR, some of them transient, in this case and at this moment it's probably the sandbox bug causing sandbox account emails to be unconfirmed.

Confirm the email via:

1. https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email -- Log in with sandbox receiver email, and re-send confirmation message.
2. https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fnotifications%2F -- log in with live account, to retrieve confirmation from Notifications tab.

---

Separately from the above, it appears you are integrating a deprecated v1 payments API.  You should be using the v2/checkout/orders API, documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

You want the step 'Set Up Transaction' and 'Capture Transaction'.  An intervening authorization step (before the capture) with intent:authorize is optional, only do this if you have very specific and well-defined business needs for that extra step.

The best front-end UI to use for customer approval is: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout-v4/#/pattern/server , as it uses no redirects and keeps your site loaded in the background. This provides the most modern, "in context" experience.

Answer (score 0):

This is an internal error from Paypal.

I would submit a ticket with the debug_id to https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/home

Below are some links with the same error. Maybe it will help point you in the right direction.

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/REST-APIs/INTERNAL-SERVICE-ERROR-REST-v1-payments-payment/td-p/1480048#

[PayPal REST Sandbox API giving INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38804016/paypal-rest-sandbox-api-giving-internal-service-error)